# Как правильно распределить архитектуру для простого crud приложения с использованием JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, репозиторий

Всем доброго дня. Начал изучать Java EE и решил подтянуть знания jdbc. Создал простой проект пока что только с моделями и репозиториями со стандартными crud методами для каждой модели (прикрепляю фото). Дальше не очень понимаю, какой слой создать для непосредственной связи с БД. Подскажите, пожалуйста. (приложение планирую делать без ui, просто статически все описать в мейне тоже самом для изучения основных методов работы jdbc). Заранее спасибо за внимание и ответ[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зачем статически?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы выделила в архитектуре такого приложения следующие слои: entity (это у вас в папке models), repository, service, controller, validator, dto и mapper. В случае простого CRUD-приложения слой service просто повторяет слой repository, так что в целом можно его не создавать. В controller нужно описать, что дальше делать с полученными объектами. Пример controller-а, который только выдаёт данные:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserRoleController {
    private final IUserRoleService userRoleService;

    @GetMapping("/user_roles")
    public List<UserRoleDTO> getUserRoles() {
        List<UserRole> userRoles = userRoleService.findAll();
        return UserRoleMapper.INSTANCE.toDTOs(userRoles);
    }

    @GetMapping("/user_roles/{id}")
    public UserRoleDTO getUserRoleById(@PathVariable Short id) {
        UserRole userRole = userRoleService.getRoleById(id);
        return UserRoleMapper.INSTANCE.toDTO(userRole);
    }
}
```

Validator проверяет корректность данных в объектах (например, длина названия альбома - от 5 до 30 символов). Пример шаблона validator-а, от которого бы наследовались классы Validator-ов для проверки объектов конкретных классов:

```
public interface IValidator<T> {
    public void checkValidityOrThrown(T obj) throws Exception;
}
```

DTO - data transfer object - нужны, когда объекты слоя entity ссылаются друг на друга (например, Album содержит список объектов Track, но одновременно Track содержит ссылку на Album, к которому он принадлежит). Если у вас нет такого, то дальнейшая информация вам, быть может, и не пригодится.

Иначе, для избежания рекурсивного перенаправления при попытке получить данные из объектов, нужно создать DTO - объекты, которые практически повторяют поля объектов слоя entity, с одним отличием, что у одного из классов рекурсивной связи не будет ссылки на объекты второго класса. Например, Entity роли пользователя (UserRole) имеет id, name, shownName, а также список пользователей (ссылку на сущности User). DTO роли пользователя имеет всё из этого, кроме списка пользователей User, так как сущность User в слое Entity также имеет ссылку на роль пользователя UserRole. Поэтому DTO для UserRole выглядит следующим образом:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class UserRoleDTO {
    private Short id;
    private String name;
    private String shownName;
}
```

Для того, чтобы не писать ручками конвертеры объектов слоя Entity в объекты слоя DTO, используются Mapper-ы. Есть библиотека mapstruct, которая позволяет легко это делать. Пример Mapper-а для сущности UserRole:

```
@Mapper
public interface UserRoleMapper {
    public UserRoleMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(UserRoleMapper.class);

    public UserRoleDTO toDTO(UserRole userRole);
    public List<UserRoleDTO> toDTOs(List<UserRole> userRoles);
    public UserRole fromDTO(UserRoleDTO userRoleDTO);
}
```